# debg consoule error Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Database with SQLite in flutter I did three functions 1-Creating database 2- Insert into the database 3-Get data from the database, my app is about to enter the task and date of start and due date then print the tasks so when I run the app it must show int console 'database created, database opened, the table created and those sentences I wrote' but when I run the app this error shows up to me.

```
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52431/lFIqFZgcPT4=/ws
 Running with sound null safety
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52431/lFIqFZgcPT4=/ws
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:52322/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:52322/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

I tried to restart the app and flutter run, flutter clean and nothing worked

functions I wrote :

```
void createDatabase() async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    database = await openDatabase(
      'todo.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (database, version) {
        print('database created');
        database
            .execute(
                'create table tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , title TEXT , date TEXT , time TEXT , status TEXT)')
            .then((value) {
          print('table created');
        }).catchError(
          (error) {
            print('error when creating table ${error.toString()}');
          },
        ); //catcherror
      },
      onOpen: (database) {
        getDataFromDatabase(database);
        print('datatbase opened');
        print('get from database done');
      },
    ); //opendatabase
  } //createdatabase

  //Inserting to the database
  Future insertToDatabase({
    required String title,
    required String time,
    required String date,
  }) async {
    return await database!.transaction((txn) async {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO tasks(title,date,time,status) VALUES("$title","$time","$date","new")')
          .then((value) {
        print("$value Inserted succesfully");
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Error when interting new record ${error.toString()}");
      });
    });
  } //insert to database

  void getDataFromDatabase(database) async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    List<Map> tasks = await database!.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tasks');
    print(tasks);
  }
}
```

[image: Pubsbec.yaml]

code of the app :

```
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_import

import 'package:app1/modules/archive%20tasks/Archived_tasks.dart';
import 'package:app1/modules/done%20tasks/Done_tasks.dart';
import 'package:app1/modules/newtasks/New_tasks.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class Home_Layout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Home_LayoutState createState() => Home_LayoutState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class Home_LayoutState extends State<Home_Layout> {
//1-create database and create tables
//2-open database
//3- insert to database
//4-get from Database
//5-update in Database
//6-delete from database

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  int Currentindex = 0;

  Database? database;

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var Scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool isBottomSheetShown = false;

  IconData fabicon = Icons.add;

  List<Widget> screens = [
    New_Tasks(),
    Done_Tasks(),
    Archived_Tasks(),
  ];

  List<String> titles = [
    'New Tasks',
    'Done Tasks',
    'Archived Tasks',
  ];

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var TitleController = TextEditingController();

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var TimeController = TextEditingController();

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var DateController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    createDatabase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: Scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          titles[Currentindex],
        ),
      ),
      body: screens[Currentindex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (isBottomSheetShown) {
            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              insertToDatabase(
                title: TitleController.text,
                time: TimeController.text,
                date: DateController.text,
              ).then(
                (value) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  isBottomSheetShown = false;
                  setState(() {
                    fabicon = Icons.add;
                  });
                },
              );
            }
          } else {
            Scaffoldkey.currentState!
                .showBottomSheet(
                  (context) => Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Form(
                      key: formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: TitleController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Task Title',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.title,
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return ('Title must not be empty');
                              } else
                                return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: TimeController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Task Time',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.watch_later_outlined,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showTimePicker(
                                context: context,
                                initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                              ).then(
                                (value) {
                                  TimeController.text =
                                      value!.format(context).toString();
                                  print(value.format(context));
                                },
                              );
                              print('timing tapped');
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return ('Time must not be empty');
                              } else
                                return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: DateController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Task Date',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.calendar_today,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showDatePicker(
                                context: context,
                                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                                lastDate: DateTime.parse('2022-06-07'),
                              ).then(
                                (value) {
                                  print(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(value!));
                                  DateController.text =
                                      DateFormat.yMMMd().format(value);
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return ('date must not be empty');
                              } else
                                return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .closed
                .then((value) {
              isBottomSheetShown = false;
              setState(() {
                fabicon = Icons.add;
              });
            }); //bottomsheet
            isBottomSheetShown = true;
            setState(
              () {
                fabicon = Icons.edit;
              },
            );
          }
        },
        child: Icon(
          fabicon,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 15.0,
        currentIndex: Currentindex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            Currentindex = index;
            print(Currentindex);
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
            ),
            label: 'Tasks',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.check_circle_outline,
            ),
            label: 'Done',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.archive_outlined,
            ),
            label: 'Archived',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Future<String> getname() async {
  //   return 'Ahmed Ali';
  // }

  void createDatabase() async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    database = await openDatabase(
      'todo.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (database, version) {
        print('database created');
        database
            .execute(
                'create table tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , title TEXT , date TEXT , time TEXT , status TEXT)')
            .then((value) {
          print('table created');
        }).catchError(
          (error) {
            print('error when creating table ${error.toString()}');
          },
        ); //catcherror
      },
      onOpen: (database) {
        getDataFromDatabase(database);
        print('datatbase opened');
        print('get from database done');
      },
    ); //opendatabase
  } //createdatabase

  //Inserting to the database
  Future insertToDatabase({
    required String title,
    required String time,
    required String date,
  }) async {
    return await database!.transaction((txn) async {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO tasks(title,date,time,status) VALUES("$title","$time","$date","new")')
          .then((value) {
        print("$value Inserted succesfully");
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Error when interting new record ${error.toString()}");
      });
    });
  } //insert to database

  void getDataFromDatabase(database) async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    List<Map> tasks = await database!.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tasks');
    print(tasks);
  }
}
```

Comment: The plugin you are using is only available for macOS, iOS and Android. What os are you running on? Maybe you are running on the wrong system?

Comment: i run on chrome